# Moved to new server, using https, but css and js requests are http

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I have a Drupal 7 site that has been working fine for years. I want to force all requests to be treated as https, so this is in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It's hosted on an AWS Lightsail server. We just added an AWS load balancer to the mix, and now, when I make an http request to the server, the page is loading, but all the requests for js and css files are treated as http requests. I've restarted the server, flushed browser, even rebooted my Mac. The only other change was the DNS now points to the load balancer. I don't know what effect the load balancer has on this, if any. When I view source of another server running a different Drupal site, I see the URLs for css and js are all https. Shouldn't Drupal be rewriting the requests to https on the broken server too?

Comment: "the page is loading, but all the requests for js and css files are treated as http requests" - is the page itself redirected to HTTPS? And where exactly have you put the above redirect in your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1):

> the page is loading, but all the requests for js and css files are treated as http requests.

It sounds like you may have put the redirect directives in the wrong place. If you put them near the end of the `.htaccess` file, specifically *after* the front-controller (Drupal directives) then any requests for static resources (eg. JS and CSS files) will not be redirected.

This redirect needs to go near the top of the `.htaccess`, before any existing rewrites.

> When I view source of another server running a different Drupal site, I see the URLs for css and js are all https.

However, you do need to actually change the URLs in the HTML source to point directly to HTTPS, otherwise, you are going to get a lot of mixed content warnings when viewing the page itself over HTTPS and the resources will fail to load. Simply implementing a "redirect" will not resolve this.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. White. I have a similar server running in another Lightsail instance. And the .htaccess is the same for both server. And the one in question used to work just fine before we started using a load balancer. Both servers have identical configurations, including the load balancer. And as far as the rewriting of urls, the server that is working has the css links as https, the broken one has http. I'm not aware of any Drupal settings that would affect this. I'm not using the secure pages module. Quite baffling.

Comment: @pglatz The code in `.htaccess` doesn't do anything with the actual links in the HTML source if that is what you are thinking? If you are seeing HTTPS links (to the CSS and JS) on one and HTTP on another then that is something different entirely - that needs to be changed in your application somewhere.